# Match two values in two columns and return yes if there appear in a different sheet

Tags: excel, matching

I am trying to figure out if a list of instrument serial numbers and their customer names that I have in Sheet 2 appear as part of a larger spreadsheet in Sheet 1.

In Sheet 1, serial numbers are in column A and names are in column M.
In Sheet 2, serial numbers are in column B and names are in column C.

I can return B2 in D2 of Sheet 2 using the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, 'Sheet 1'!A:A, 1, FALSE)
```

However, that does not match columns B and C, so I've been playing with the following formula for column D of sheet 2 (doesn't work, but it's what I think is the start to something):

```
=MATCH(1,IF(B2='Sheet 1'!$A:A, IF(C2='Sheet 1'!M:M,1,0),0),0)
```

My questions:

1. How do I correctly confirm that B2 and C2 appear in the same row of Sheet 1?
2. Is there a better function than `VLOOKUP` that outputs `"TRUE"`, `"1"`, or the statement of my choosing (`"yes"`) if a match is found?

Comment: You are looking for the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) and it would look something like this: `=IF(COUNTIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A,B2,'Sheet 1'!M:M,C2)>0,"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 0):

You can vlookup and then use an if clause to check if the corresponding M column matches the B column

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$6,$A$2:$M$6,13)=B2,"Yes","No")

Sheet 1
A    M  
1   One
2   Two
3   tree
4   fr
5   fv

   Sheet 2 data     Sheet2 D Col
    A     B
    1    One                Yes
    2    Two                Yes
    3    Three              No
    4    Four Five          No
    5    Five               No
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this formula on `column D` and drag down:

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$M$4,13,0)`

The 3rd parameter in `VLOOKUP` is the column number of the range (the range here is from `column A to M`) so that way it knows where to match.

You can also use `INDEX/MATCH` such as:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$M$2:$M$4,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,0))`

Both should work for your task.